# How to share HttpSecurity in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with request filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application where I configured REST security with JWT authentication overriding the

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
```

method in my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
        .csrf().disable()
        // ...
        .authorizeRequests()
        // ...
        .antMatchers("/api/authentication/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/assets/*/processed-data/csv").permitAll()
        // ...
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        // ...
```

Since some paths require authentication, while others don't, I'd like to pair that configuration in the respective JWT token verification filter, where I'm actually listing each subpath:

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    // ...
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/api/authentication/")) {
            // ...
```

`HttpSecurity` is not a bean so I can't autowire it. What can I do? Should I make my `WebSecurityConfig` class a bean and add a `getHttpSecurity()` method? Is there a cleaner way? Or is this approach not recommended at all?

Comment: Why would you need that in your filter? That filter should be part of the security chain, if you haven't make it so. Else you have 2 security solutions.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not sure to understand, I wrote that filter looking at some guides about Spring and JWT (i.e. [this one](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt)); if I implemented them right, that filter is part of the security solution, it checks that the token is present and valid, but of course it is complaining about absent tokens on paths where it is not really requested, since it is triggered on all paths (generating false positives in log files).

Comment: And it should trigger on all paths. It should just ignore the fact that it isn't available instead of blowing up. You are now trying to mix `authentication` and `authorization` (kind of) in a single filter. What that filter should do is, if header present fill authentication, if not leave it be and the rest will be handled by Spring Security. If you implemented that filter one-on-one just remove the logging or make it smarter (that it ignores the absence of the header). Adding `if(requestTokenHeader == null) { filterchain.doFilter(request, response, chain);}` will solve the excessive logging.

Comment: @M.Deinum I see, so I shouln't differ among requests with expired token and requests with no token at all?

Comment: No. I explicitly stated if there is **no** token just continue the chain. If there is a token you want to validate and process it.